# Set a field from parent type from child data fetcher using GraphQL in Java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

Query:

```
type query {
  someQuery: ParentType
}

type ParentType {
  name: String
  errors: Error
  child: ChildType
}

type ChildType {
  name: String
}

type Error {
  type: String
  name: String
}
```

I will have resolvers for `someQuery` and `child` and corresponding data fetchers. I wanted to set errors from child data fetcher. This GraphQL API is written in Java. How can I achieve this using `DataFetchingEnvironment`.

Answer (score -1):

While you *can* mutate the parent from inside a child resolver:

```
Parent parent = dataFetchingEnv.getSource();
parent.errors = ...; //set the errors on parent
```

this is utterly awful design. Depending on the order the fields are resolved, you may or may not get the result you want. With graphql-java's default strategy, and with all resolvers being synchronous, you'll get one result for:

```
{someQuery {name, child {name}, errors {name, type}}} //errors populated
```

and a different result for:

```
{someQuery {name, errors {name, type}, child {name}}} //no errors
```

And if you have async resolvers, you'll get seemingly random results. Also what if the child isn't even selected? The parent should decidedly *not* change based on the sub-selection. You really should come up with a better schema.